# Append to large number of files

Tags: linux, database, filesystems

I am looking DB that mimics filesystem (or just filesystem) that allows to have many opened files and append data. By default Linux has 1024 open file limit. Currently I close/open files and I have some cache of open files but I am sure it could be done better and I do not wish to reinvent the wheel.

I was advised to use Cassandra but it seems too much for me right now.

I have 1 million files to append right now. I think my server can handle 10 million files with pattern I have.

Comment: You can easily adjust the 1024 limit, but I'm not sure if having 10M open FDs is a good idea. What kind of data are you appending, and how much of it is there?

Comment: Maybe [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It is like IoT sensors but they are in virtual reality. We need append and select data for certain sensor. So file sounds like a perfect choice. Databases start working slower more data you add. I do not wish to design framework that caches opened files if there is something similar already developed. or framework that writes to single file and then when 100MB is written distributes in large number of files.